# php file upload " $_File " returns empty array while debuging

Tags: php, file

I'm  using  a free web host for my php script this is my code

```html
 
 print_r($_FILES);
 
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
 echo "file name =".$_FILES['file'.$i]['name'];
 $file_name = $_FILES['file'.$i]['name'];
 
 if($file_name){
  $ext = end((explode(".", $file_name)));
    
    echo "<br>flag =  $ext <br>";
    // strip file_name of slashes
    $file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
    $file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
    $file_name = "Produit".$idp."-".$i.".".$ext;
    
    
    $copy = copy($_FILES['file'.$i]['tmp_name'],"ProduitImages/".$idproduit."/".$file_name);
    
     // prompt if successfully copied
     if($copy){
     echo "$file_name | uploaded sucessfully!<br>";
     }else{
     echo "$file_name | could not be uploaded!<br>";
     }
 }{
  echo "<br>file $i not sent<br>";
 }
```

on my localhost it's working with no problems.

So, why in the host the $_Files is empty and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

and this is my html code

```html
<div class="input-file-container">
      <label for="my-file" class="input-file-trigger" tabindex="0">please Select all 5 images </label>
      <input class="input-file" id="file0" name="file0" type="file">
      <input class="input-file" id="file1" name="file1" type="file">
      <input class="input-file" id="file2" name="file2" type="file">
      <input class="input-file" id="file3" name="file3" type="file">
      <input class="input-file" id="file4" name="file4" type="file">
     </div>
```

and this is the  result

```html
Array ( )
Notice: Undefined index: file0 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 131


file name =
Notice: Undefined index: file0 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 132



file 0 not sent

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 131


file name =
Notice: Undefined index: file1 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 132



file 1 not sent

Notice: Undefined index: file2 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 131


file name =
Notice: Undefined index: file2 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 132



file 2 not sent

Notice: Undefined index: file3 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 131


file name =
Notice: Undefined index: file3 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 132


file 3 not sent

Notice: Undefined index: file4 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 131


file name =
Notice: Undefined index: file4 in /home/vhosts/websitename.freeoda.com/Name/includes/vishandler.php on line 132



file 4 not sent
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: it is still the *same*,  Undefined *index* :/

Comment: `Undefined index` *what?* and the full notice. Post your HTML form that goes with this.

Comment: `file_uploads` may be disabled on that host. Please check via `<?php echo ini_get('file_uploads'); ?>` (must be `1` if enabled).

Comment: i'll run it now "<?php echo ini_get('file_uploads'); ?>"

Comment: the return was " 1 "

Comment: R u using encrypted multipart in form

Comment: yes i'm using ' enctype="multipart/form-data" '

Comment: i don't know why but this code is working on my localhost but not on the webhost

Comment: is there any other way to do it?